# Select with where param in php and oracle

Tags: php, oracle, select

I'm doing a select with where via PHP and Oracle, when I get the parameter an error occurs:

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\includes\Read.php on line 52 Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\index.php on line

If I pass the direct parameter works normally, as commented line, it works.

```
public function readAnexos($CDLICITACAO) {

    try {
        //$id = '012103';
        $id = $CDLICITACAO;

        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = $id";
        $stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql_query);

        oci_execute($stid);
        return $stid;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>Error na linha:  ";
        echo "<b>" . $e->getTraceAsString()."</b>";
        parent::fechar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really important to use bind variables.  This is for security and performance.

Try at least:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO = :id";
$stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql_query);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":id", $CDLICITACAO);
oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: Not working, return empty... with vardump in variable $stid = resource(8) of type (oci8 statement)

Comment: You need to post more detail, in particular the table schema, sample data used in PHP and full errors.  Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);  // In PHP 5.3 use E_ALL|E_STRICT
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: If you change the $CDLICITACAO variable to '101010' it works

Comment: If you don't want to share the info I asked for, all I can say is 'keep debugging'

Comment: Debugging he had printed this,

resource (9) of type (oci8 statement) resource (9) of type (oci8 statement) string (63) "SELECT * FROM TBLICITCAO WHERE CDLICITACAO =: id" string (20) "014384"

Comment: Genereta two erros

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\includes\Read.php on line 52

line 52: oci_execute($stid);


Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\index.php on line 72

line 72: while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
    $dataAnexos[] = array("IDANEXO" => $row['IDANEXO'],
                    "CDLICITACAO"   => $row['CDLICITACAO'],
                    "NARQUIVO"      => $row['NARQUIVO'],
                    "DIRARQUIVO"    => $row['DIRARQUIVO']);
}

Comment: I changed the query from sql to like and now it does not return error, only:
Resource id #8